# Closedness of the set $A = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \geq g(x)\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $(X, \Vert\cdot\Vert_X)$ be a normed space and the functions $f, g : X \to \mathbb R$ continuous. Show that the set $A = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \geq g(x)\}$ is closed.

#### A failed attempt

We should show that $f(x) \geq g(x)$, when $x$ is an arbitrary accumulation point of $A$.

The functions $f$ and $g$ are continuous, so for every $\varepsilon_1> 0$ there is a $\delta_1 > 0$, for which
$$
\Vert x - x_n \Vert_X < \delta_1 \quad\Rightarrow\quad \Vert f(x) - f(x_n) \Vert_Y < \varepsilon_1,
$$
where now $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ and $x_n$ a member of a sequence $(x_n) \subset A : x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$. The same continuity condition holds for the function $g$, possibly with different $\varepsilon_2$ and $\delta_2$.

We also know, that for a member of the sequence $(x_n) \subset A$, $f(x_n) \geq g(x_n)$. Intuitively, as we then approach the accumulation point $x$ from inside the set and the functions are continuous, $f$ should stay above $g$ as we hit $x$.

But how do I state this mathematically?
Should I observe how the difference $\Vert f(x) - g(x_n)\Vert$ is always greater than the difference $\Vert f(x) - f(x_n)\Vert_Y$ for all $x_n$ somehow? My guess is that I should show that I can choose a $\delta$ (maybe $\Vert f(x_n) - g(x_n)\Vert_Y$), but is that really the direction I should take?

I am especially interested in arguments based on the definitions of closedness in terms of accumulation points and continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $h=f-g$ is continuous and$$A=h^{-1}\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr).$$Since $[0,\infty)$ is closed, $A$ is closed too.

---

Here's another approach, which proves that $A^\complement$ is an open set. Take $x\in A^\complement$. Then $h(x)<0$. Therefore, since $h$ is continuous, there is a $r>0$ such that$$\lVert y-x\rVert<r\implies\bigl\lvert h(y)-h(x)\bigr\rvert<\bigl\lvert h(x)\bigr\rvert\implies h(y)<0.$$But then $B_r(x)\subset A^\complement$. Since, for each $x\in A^\complement$, there is an open ball centered at $x$ and contained in $A^\complement$, $A^\complement$ is an open set.

Comment: Ok, that is handy, but can this be done using the definitions of continuity and closedness?

Comment: @SeSodesa Done.

Comment: Should $h(x) > 0$, instead of $h(x) < 0$, in the case where $x \in A$?

Comment: No, since I am working on $A^\complement$ and$$x\in A^\complement\iff f(x)<g(x)\iff h(x)<0.$$

Comment: Ah right, $\complement$ is for complement, not closure...

Comment: Yes, the closure of $A$ is $\overline A$.

Comment: By the way, are both $x$ and $y$ in $A^\complement$, or is $y \in X$ arbitrarily.

Comment: I assumed that $y\in X$ and then I deduced that $y\in A^\complement$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then for sufficiently large $n$, we have $|f(x)-f(x_n)|<\epsilon$ and $|g(x)-g(x_n)|<\epsilon$, so
$$f(x)-g(x)=(f(x)-f(x_n))+(f(x_n)-g(x_n))+(g(x_n)-g(x)) \geq -2\epsilon.$$
Notice the left hand side does not depend on $\epsilon$. So we have $f(x)-g(x) \geq -2\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, which implies $f(x)-g(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: Does this hold even if the norm in question isn't the absolute value function, as in $\Vert\cdot\Vert \neq |\cdot|$?

Comment: No, I used the fact that if $|f(x)-f(x_n)|<\epsilon$ then $-\epsilon < f(x)-f(x_n)<\epsilon$. Are you not using the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}$ though? To be clear, the norm on $X$ can be anything, I haven't made any assumptions about that.

Comment: Well, I am very inexperienced but still decided to take on a functional analysis course, where the norm in general is defined as any function that satisfies the norm axioms. So $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is not necessarily the absolute value function.

Comment: Right, but I'm asking about the norm being used on the codomain $\mathbb{R}$, not the domain $X$. If you say $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then you need some norm on $X$ (which is $\|\cdot\|$) and some norm on $\mathbb{R}$ (which is unspecified). In the absence of any other information, one would typically assume the usual norm $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Notice that the points $f(x), f(x_n),g(x),g(x_n)$ are all in $\mathbb{R}$, so the norms $|f(x)-f(x_n)|$ and so on are taken in $\mathbb{R}$, not in $X$. It might be confusing you to use $\|\cdot\|$ as both the norm in $X$ and the norm in $\mathbb{R}$ as you have done in your question. I edited my answer to use $|\cdot|$ as the norm in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Just today our teacher commented on this, saying he leaves out the sub-index specifying the norm in question, if he talks about general norms. I guess I should update the question to reflect this. There is nothing in the assignment requiring the norm to be the absolute value function.

Answer (score 1):

$h(x) =f(x)-g(x)$, $x \in X$ ;

Show that $A^c=\{h(x) <0| x \in X\}$ is open.

Let $x_0  \in A^c $, then $h(x_0) <0$.

Since $h$ continuos:

$\epsilon >0$ given, there is a $\delta$ s.t.

$||x-x_0|| <\delta$ implies $|h(x)-h(x_0)| <\epsilon$.

$-\epsilon +h(x_0) <h(x)<\epsilon +h(x_0)$.

Choose $\epsilon =-h(x_0)/2 >0$.

Then:

There is a $\delta_0$ s.t. $||x-x_0|| <\delta_0$ implies

$h(x) <\epsilon + h(x_0) = h(x_0)/2<0$, i.e.

$B_{\delta_0}(x_0) \subset A^c$.

$A^c$ is open, hence  $A$ is closed.

Comment: Notice, that the norm defined on the codomain of $f$ and $g$ in question isn't necessarily the absolute value function. In other words, it doens't necessarily hold that $\Vert\cdot\Vert = |\cdot|$

Comment: Sesodesa. || || does not necessarily equal | | , but did I assume this?

Comment: @PeterSzilas When you went from $|h(x)-h(x_0)|<\epsilon$ to $-\epsilon+h(x_0)<h(x)<\epsilon + h(x_0)$ you assumed the usual norm on $\mathbb{R}$ is being used. Apparently that might not be the case.

Comment: Not sure. I saw the $|\cdot|$ notation instead of the $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ one, so I assumed that you did. @kccu just commented on all norms being equivalent on $\mathbb R$, but I don't believe we covered that yet in our lectures or lecture notes.

Comment: @SeSodesa I've deleted that comment because I know it's true for vector space norms, but I'm not sure whether it holds in general.

Comment: @kccu Well, this course is taken in the context of vector spaces, so I think you were safe to assume that.

Comment: kccu.Oops Yes assumed the usual norm on R.Thanks.